# Is OAuth viable for my website's API?

Tags: php, api, oauth

I'm developing a social networking website. This service will be available across various mediums, for example: the web, iPhone, Facebook application etc.

My idea for this application was to have all of these properties interact with one central point for fetching and saving data: an API. My various applications would then interact with this API, sending a `GET` request to fetch some data; a `POST` request to submit some data; `DELETE` requests and so on.

This API will be web-accessible, so I need a way to authenticate only white-listed applications. This API will never be available for third parties to interact with or build third-party applications with; it's to facilitate my applications only so I can cut out re-coding solutions across various platforms and focus only on the logic (controllers, essentially).

Therefore, would OAuth be suitable to be used as the authentication method for the above scenario?

My knowledge of OAuth isn't great, but if it is deemed a viable solution then I'll obviously read up on it before implementing. But as far as I know it works on tokens. A consumer (for example, my website) would request a token from the application (the API in this instance) and then the application would return a token to use in subsequent requests. Or something.

When a request comes in to my application, am I then able to accept/deny requests based on the requesting application? I.e. can I deny access to applications that aren't my own? How do I differentiate between applications? Do I retain a whitelist of IP address or URLs, and compare upon incoming requests?

Any help on the above would be most appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought about implementing Message Authentication Code (MAC)? That is what most APIs I see these days work with (including mine). With a proper implementation, you can accept/deny requests based on the requesting application, retain request information, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth is not designed to authenticate some applications the way you want to.

Juste create your own private way to authenticate, because you're the only one to know about your API. Dont forget to pipe the authentication in SSL and everything will be ok !

Answer (score 1):

I don't think OAuth is the best solution for your problem. OAuth is great when you plan to give your API to the 3rd parties as it allows to authenticate user without giving users's credentials to the 3rd party. If you have all control over the API there is no need for this. 
It's still a good idea to read about it thou. :)